# Architecture: Spring hibernate Application with Web Interface on one server and Persistence layer on a differ Server

Tags: hibernate, spring, remoting, architecture

I am working on a web application, the main technologies used are JSP,Spring framework and hibernate. In a typical scenario the request is intercepted by the controllers which in turn talk to the Services and then Services talk to DAOs. Right now the application is hosted by a single JBOSS server.  I am in an urgent need of a solution to an architectural setup. I need to put the web interface on a different JBOSS server and the services(Persistence layer) on a different JBOSS server behind the firewall. I have no idea how to go about this the only thing I can think of right now is using web services. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Manu

Answer (score 0):

[Spring remoting](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) would answer this. The HTTP invoker mechanism of spring (2nd point in the linked docs) is the easiest and most efficient way to do this.

It's not unlikely to have some problems with lazy initialization. You'd have to initialize collections fully before transferring them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think this might help.